# Why do I get an error while resolving the Pluralization Service in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code in my Context class. Straight from this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164) .

```
    private string GetTableName(Type type)
    {
        var pluralizationService = DbConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService<IPluralizationService>();
        var result = pluralizationService.Pluralize(type.Name);
        result = Regex.Replace(result, ".[A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + "_" + m.Value[1]);
        return result.ToUpper();
    }
```

The error I get is `The non-generic method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.IDbDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type, object)' cannot be used with type arguments` I am thinking either I am missing a using clause. Or there is a problem with entity framework 6.0.1. I can't find what library do I need to include, other than  System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Pluralization.

Comment: Are you getting the error on the line `var result = pluralizationService.Pluralize(type.Name);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add `using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution;`

Comment: That is the right answer. But, how is it that the compiler emits an error referring to the namespace that is missing?

Comment: The problem is an extension method that you're missing, I think,.